# How to render another resource's form in active admin dashboard - Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

Well I have a bill resource and I want the form of bill resource to be displayed in active admin dashboard.MY code look likes ->

## apps/views/admin/dashboard/_form.html.arb

```
 active_admin_form_for bill do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    inputs 'Enter the bill details' do
       input :amount
       input :is_paid        
       actions
    end
 end
```

---

## dashboard.rb

```
 ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do    
   menu priority: 1, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }    
      content title: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do    
        form render 'form'
      end
 end
```

But I am getting only black space for this form in dashboard!
pls help me out !

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your render line with `render partial: 'form'`